# Saber qué columnas han cambiado en una tabla del Dataset

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Buenos días:

Hay alguna manera de saber qué columnas han cambiado en un registro que he cargado previamente?
Me explico:
tengo un programa en el que cargo un alumno. Cuando voy a volver a cargar otro desde el botón de buscar, antes compruebo si hay cambios en el anterior y me dice siempre que hay cambios pendientes de guardar. He probado a cargar el mismo registro y también me dice que hay cambios. Hay alguna manera para saber qué columnas se han cambiado? 
El código que tengo para comprobar si habían cambios es este pero por más que busco no sé cómo hacer para que me diga las columnas:

```
Me.Validate()
Me.ALUMNOSBindingSource.EndEdit()
If Me.DatasetALUMNOS.HasChanges Then
   If MsgSalirSinGuardar() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No Then
      bolCargar = False
   End If
End If
```

He visto que está esto:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130902/datarow-getchanges-or-equivalent

Pero en mi caso yo sé la fila que ha cambiado, lo que necesito saber es la columna o columnas que se han modificado.

Gracias.

Comment: María,en la pregunta que enlazas tienes exactamente la solución. Tienes un método que utiliza las diferentes versiones del DataRow para comprobar si ha habido algun cambio, lo único que tienes que hacer es llamar a ese método en un `foreach` para cada columna de tu datarow. Que problema tienes con la solución que enlazas?

Comment: El lenguaje de programación. Que me estoy haciendo un lío si te soy sincera.

Comment: Maria, mira mi respuesta. Es en realidad una conversión del código de la respuesta que enlazas a Vb.net, con alguna pequeña explicación de su funcionamiento. Si tienes dudas me comentas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La pregunta es tal vez un poco extensa, pero parece que puede ser interesante para mas gente, así que paso a dar una solución.Primero, añade un módulo a tu proyecto, y llámalo `DataRowExtensions` por ejemplo. Luego añades el siguiente código:

```vb
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module DataRowExtensions

    Private Function hasCellChanged(ByVal row As DataRow, ByVal col As DataColumn) As Boolean
        If Not row.HasVersion(DataRowVersion.Original) Then
            Return True
        End If

        If Not row.HasVersion(DataRowVersion.Current) Then
            Return False
        End If

        Dim originalVersion = row(col, DataRowVersion.Original)
        Dim currentVersion = row(col, DataRowVersion.Current)
        If originalVersion Is DBNull.Value AndAlso currentVersion Is DBNull.Value Then
            Return False
        ElseIf originalVersion IsNot DBNull.Value AndAlso currentVersion IsNot DBNull.Value Then
            Return Not originalVersion.Equals(currentVersion)
        End If

        Return True
    End Function

    <Extension()>
    Public Function GetChangedColumns(ByVal row As DataRow) As IEnumerable(Of DataColumn)
        Return row.Table.Columns.Cast(Of DataColumn)().Where(Function(col) hasCellChanged(row, col))
    End Function

    <Extension()>
    Public Function GetChangedColumns(ByVal rows As IEnumerable(Of DataRow)) As IEnumerable(Of DataColumn)
        Return rows.SelectMany(Function(row) row.GetChangedColumns()).Distinct()
    End Function

    <Extension()>
    Public Function GetChangedColumns(ByVal table As DataTable) As IEnumerable(Of DataColumn)
        Return table.GetChanges().Rows.Cast(Of DataRow)().GetChangedColumns()
    End Function

End Module
```

Este código hace uso de una característica de los DataRows, y es que almacenan varias versiones de las columnas (ver [DataRowVersions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.datarowversion(v=vs.110).aspx)), entre ellas la versión original y la actual. Debes tener en cuenta que una vez utilizas [`AcceptChanges`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.datatable.acceptchanges(v=vs.110).aspx) en tu `DataTable`, la versión `Original` del `DataRow` se sobreescribe con la versión `Current`.

Para usar estas extensiones, simplemente debes hacer lo siguiente:

```vb
'Comprobamos primero que exista algun DataRow con cambios
If Not IsNothing(Me.DatasetALUMNOS.Tables(0).GetChanges()) Then

    Dim columnasCambiadas As List(Of DataColumn) = Me.DatasetALUMNOS.Tables(0).GetChangedColumns().ToList()
    If (columnasCambiadas.Count > 0) Then
         'hay cambios en al menos una de las columnas de alguna fila del Dataset
         ' en columnasCambiadas tenemos todas las que tienen algun cambio, podemos recorrerlas en un bucle para consultarlas.
    End If
End If
```

Comment: He hecho un copy-paste de toda la vida y en el código he importado el módulo. Pero hay algo que no entiendo: cómo puede ser que en la cuenta de las columnasCambiadas me diga que no es mayor que 0 pero después en el`If Me.DatasetALUMNOS.HasChanges Then` me diga que sí que hay cambios?
Lo había dejado sin querer y mientras uno me dice que no hay cambios, el otro dice que sí.

Comment: @Maria A ver, son dos cosas diferentes. `HasChanges` lo único que te indica es si ha habido cambios en el dataset (o sea, filas añadidas,quitadas o modificadas). Los métodos que yo te he puesto aqui, analizan cada fila viendo si se ha modificado alguna columna. Es un poco complicado, lo entiendo, pero para responderte mejor necesitaría saber exactamente en qué situación se produce lo que me cuentas.

Comment: Busco un alumno y luego llamo a una función para cargarlo que antes comprueba si hay cambios o no y avisa en caso de que sí. La primera vez que busco un Alumno no dice nada porque no hay cambios (obvio), pero cuando busco otro me dice que hay cambios pendientes de guardar (el HasChanges). En el DataSet tengo más tablas pero son todas para mostrar datos y no hago nada más, porque la principal es la de los alumnos (las tablas maestras que tengo en una función y que se cargan en el Load con un Fill porque hay pocos valores). Antes no te lo he dicho pero muchas gracias por "traducir" el código :)

Comment: He probado a poner:
`For j = 0 To Me.Me.DatasetALUMNOS.Tables.Count - 1
    If Not IsNothing(Me.DatasetALUMNOSTables(j).GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified)) Then
        MsgBox(Me.DatasetALUMNOS.Tables(j).ToString)
   End If
Next`
Para que me dijera la tabla que se había modificado y me dice que es en la de Alumnos, pero si luego pongo lo de `columnasCambiadas.Count` me dice que el valor es 0

Comment: @Maria si el dataset tiene varias tablas, es posible que no estes consultando la que es. Si te fijas, en mi ejemplo pongo `Me.DatasetALUMNOS.Tables(0)`..., pero si hay varias tablas deberás modificarlo, algo asi como `Me.DatasetALUMNOS.Tables("Alumnos")` o la que sea. Es posible que sea ese el problema que estás teniendo. O si debes consultar varias tablas, deberas meterlo en un bucle y poner `Me.DatasetALUMNOS.Tables(i).GetChangedColumns().ToList()`

Comment: Por eso luego he hecho el For, porque ya dudo de que hasta la que se esté modificando sea esa o no. Y me dice que es la de Alumnos.

Comment: @Maria pero en donde estás llamado al `GetChangedColumns()` estas poniendo siempre `Me.DatasetALUMNOS.Tables(0)`?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69431/discussion-between-maria-and-pikoh).